# How can I get Running Services like those which are shown in Settings-> Developer Options-> Running Services

Tags: java, android

> I want to access running services or apps like clean master is showing, please guide me.

[image: Running Services in Developer Options]

[image: Running Services in Clean Master]

Comment: You need to give more information about what/why you're trying to do this so people can offer better/accurate advice. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have almost tried everything, but still I am unable to get the running services. As getRunningServices has been depricated. I am assigned a task to create an app like Clean Master, so to do so I want to access running services just like clean master or from developer options.. Screen shots are attached. I want to achieve exact same functionality.

Comment: WT*? If you people can't understand or answer the fuc***g question, then why do you rate it negatively? :@ :->

Answer (score 0):

From - [Android - getRunningservices(ActivityManager) deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519439/android-getrunningservicesactivitymanager-deprecated)

> We deliberately don't have an API to check whether a service is 
>   running because, nearly without fail, when you want to do something 
>   like that you end up with race conditions in your code.

Comment: But how is clean master able to do so?

Comment: No Idea, possibly is suppresses the deprecation warnings

Comment: How can we suppresses deprecation warnings? And if we can, then are we able to get the desired result?

Comment: Its in the linked question `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519439/android-getrunningservicesactivitymanager-deprecated