# The correct way to determine if service is running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I am running foreground services in my app and I need to deremine if they running in my activity.
From my searches I found that this is the option:

```
private fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

but:

getRunningServices(Int): is deprecated.

So I am using one of 3 ways.

1. Binding the service to the activity with onResume. But I think it a bit overkill for something small just to check if service is running.
2. Make the Intent public and check if its null, but there can be some cases where the intent not null but service not running
3. Check if the foreground service persistent notification is active, but this is workaround.

What is the most correct way to check if service is running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - getRunningservices(ActivityManager) deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519439/android-getrunningservicesactivitymanager-deprecated)

Comment: The answer is @SuppressWarnings("deprecation"), but is this the correct way, just to suppress it? I am trying to use the code as much time as possible. getRunningServices could be removed totally in couple of months.

Comment: You can use [bindService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)) and check the return value, or listen ServiceConnection callback to distinguish service type, though there may still have some problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a static boolean in the Service itself.
In onCreate make it true;
In onDestroy() make it false;

```
public class ActivityService extends Service {

public static  boolean IS_ACTIVITY_RUNNING = false;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IS_ACTIVITY_RUNNING = true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if(!IS_ACTIVITY_RUNNING)
                stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    IS_ACTIVITY_RUNNING = false;
}}
```

Now, You can check whether your activiy is running trough boolean ActivityService.IS_ACTIVITY_RUNNING

Comment: static when called from another service could lead for a leakage.

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin This is working for me->

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun <T> Context.isServiceRunning(service: Class<T>): Boolean {
    return (getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
        .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .any { it -> it.service.className == service.name }
}
```

After this you can call the function like ->

```
context.isServiceRunning(MyService::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `SharedPreferences` in the `onCreate` method of the `Service` and append some boolean value in it.

```kotlin
getSharedPreferences( getString( R.string.app_name ) , Context.MODE_PRIVATE )
     .edit()
     .putBoolean( getString( R.string.service_running_status_key ) , true )
     .apply()
```

Similarly, in the `onDestroy` method, append `false` to the same key. You can then use `SharedPreferences.getBoolean` to check if the `Service` is running in foreground.

Comment: I would not suggest using Shared Preferences to store a state flag.  If the Application crashes for some reason, then the Shared Preference would still indicate the incorrect state of the service.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, Create a @JvmStatic boolean state in companion object. Then set it to ture in onCreate and set it to false in onDestroy. Then you can read that.

```
class ScreenRecorderService : LifecycleService(){

    companion object {

        private var running = false

        @JvmStatic
        fun start(context: Context) {
            context.startService(Intent(context, ScreenRecorderService::class.java))
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun stop(context: Context) {
            context.stopService(Intent(context,     ScreenRecorderService::class.java))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        running = true
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        running = false
    }
}
```